# Faster way to read data from oracle database in R

Tags: r, rodbc

I have the following situation:

```
library(RODBC)
channel <- odbcConnect("ABC", uid="DEF", pwd="GHI")
df <- sqlQuery(channel,query)
```

The number of rows is 10M+. Is there any faster way to read the data?

The data is in oracle database.

Comment: Could you also post the "query"?

Comment: I'd suggest to output as text, then import to R, using data.table::fread, or vroom.

Comment: It is a complex query. There are multiple joins among 4-5tables.

Comment: I am looking for some functions using which data can be read quickly

Comment: Does the query run fast within oracle?

Comment: Comparatively, yes!

Comment: Then as suggested dump as text file, then read using fread.

Comment: Try using `odbc`. https://db.rstudio.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely should be a comment but will be too long for the purposes.

When executing SQL there are a few likely bottlenecks

1. Executing the query itself
2. Download the data from the database
3. Converting the data to align with language specific types (eg. `R` integers rather than `BIGINT` etc.

If your query runs fast when executed directly on the database UI, it is unlikely that the bottleneck comes when executing the query itself. This is also immediately clear if your query only contains simple `[RIGHT/LEFT/INNER/OUTER] JOIN`, as these are not "complex" query operators as such. This is more often caused by more complex nested queries using [`WITH`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause) clauses or [window functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/window-functions-usage.html). The solution here would be to create a [`VIEW`](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj15446.html) such that the query will be pre-optimized.
Now what is more likely to be the problem is 2. and 3. You state that your table has 10M data points. Lets assume your table is financial and has only 5 columns, which are all 8bit floats ( `FLOAT(8)` ) or 8 bit integers, the amount of data to be downloaded is `(8 * 5 * 10 M / 1024^3) Gbit = 0.37 Gbit`, which itself will take some time to download depending on your cconnection. Assuming you have a 10 Mbit connection the download under optimal condition would be taking at least 37 seconds. And this is the case where your data has only **5** columns! It is not unlikely that you have many more.
Now for 3. it is more difficult to predict the amount of time spent without careful code profiling. This is the step where `RODBC`, `odbc` or `RJDBC` will have to convert the data into types that `R` understands. I am sorry to say that here it becomes a question of "trial and error" to figure out which packages work best. However for oracle specifics, I would assume [`DBI`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/index.html) + [`odbc`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odbc/odbc.pdf) + [`ROracle`](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/roracle.html) (seems to be developed by oracle themselves??) would be a rather safe bet for a good contender.

Do however keep in mind, that the total time spent on getting data imported from any database into R is an aggregate of the above measures. Some databases provide optimized methods for downloading queries/tables as flat-files (csv, parquet etc) and this can in some cases speed up the query quite significantly, but at the cost of having to read from disk. This often also becomes more complex compared to executing the query itself, so one has to evaluate whether it is worth the trouble, or whether it is worth just waiting for the original query to finish executing within R.